# Difference between segmentation and partition in KDB

Tags: kdb

What is the difference between HDB segmentation and HDB partition? As per my understanding both stores the data in different partitions (based on date, month, year etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Segmented table none of the partitions are under the same root; instead  the root contains a file called `par.txt` having paths to different segments.
while in partitioned table, all the partitions are under the same root.

check out this link :  https://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/kdbplus_database

Use [.Q.par](https://code.kx.com/wiki/DotQ/DotQDotpar) to find the exact path(segment) of the a segmented table.

The main advantage the segmented DB provides is the speed while doing the map reduce operations.

Typical structure of partitioned db  :

```
/db
    [sym]
    /partition1
    /partition2
```

Typical structure of segmented db  :

```
/db
    [sym]
    par.txt
    "
==drive1====
/segment1
    /partition1
    /partition2
    "
==drive2====
/segment2
    /partition1
    /partition2
    "
```

Comment: There's a point wrt segmenting that's missing - the aspect of slicing a single partition into slices..which segmenting can only provide. Rather than provide a new answer, or bloat this comment, a better link to read is https://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/segments. By segmenting you can split each partition into separate io channels (you don't have to, but it's highly recommended), but you can then go further and horizontally dice a partition into predefined criteria. In this way, a single select query can query, in parallel, a single partition and utilize all io channels at once.